# Multidimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array of shape `(5,2)` which each row consist of an array of shape `(4,3,2)` and a float number.

After I slice that array`[:,0]`, I get an array of shape `(5,)` which each element has shape of `(4,3,2)`, instead of an array of shape `(5,4,3,2)` (even if I'd use `np.array()`).

Why?

Edited

Example:

```
a1 = np.arange(50).reshape(5, 5, 2)
a2 = np.arange(50).reshape(5, 5, 2)

b1 = 15.0
b2 = 25.0

h = []
h.append(np.array([a1, b1]))
h.append(np.array([a2, b2]))

h = np.array(h)[:,0]
np.shape(h) # (2,)
np.shape(h[0]) # (5, 5, 2)
np.shape(h[1]) # (5, 5, 2)
h = np.array(h)
np.shape(h) # (2,) Why not (2, 5, 5, 2)?
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*each row consists of an array of shape `(4,3,2)`*"? Please given an example.

Comment: First element in each row is an array of that shape.

Comment: You asked for the first column of each row. The first column is an array of shape `(4, 3, 2)`, the second column is a float. Why are you surprised that you got an array with just `(4, 3, 2)` elements?

Comment: Use `a[:,0].astype(float)`.

Comment: you should add a sample of your array

Comment: I am surprised, because I don't get a array of shape `(5,4,3,2)`.

Comment: Might be a little tedious, given that it has to contain 250 individual numeric values, unless it can be created by code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [121]: a1.dtype, a1.shape
Out[121]: (dtype('int32'), (5, 5, 2))
In [122]: c1 = np.array([a1,b1])
In [123]: c1.dtype, c1.shape
Out[123]: (dtype('O'), (2,))
```

Because `a1` and `b1` are different shaped objects (`b1` isn't even an array), an array made from them will have dtype object.  And the `h` made from several continues to be object dtype.

```
In [124]: h = np.array(h)
In [125]: h.dtype, h.shape
Out[125]: (dtype('O'), (2, 2))
In [126]: h[:,1]
Out[126]: array([15.0, 25.0], dtype=object)
In [127]: h[:,0].dtype
Out[127]: dtype('O')
```

After the appends, `h` (as an array) is object dtype.  The 2nd column is the b1 and b2 values, the 1st column the a1 and a2.

Some form of concatenate is required to combine those `a1` `a2` arrays into one.  `stack` does it on a new axis.

```
In [128]: h[0,0].shape
Out[128]: (5, 5, 2)
In [129]: np.array(h[:,0]).shape     # np.array doesn't cross the object boundary
Out[129]: (2,)
In [130]: np.stack(h[:,0]).shape
Out[130]: (2, 5, 5, 2)
In [131]: np.concatenate(h[:,0],0).shape
Out[131]: (10, 5, 2)
```

Turning the (2,) array into a list, does allow `np.array` to recombine the elements into a higher dimensional array, just as `np.stack` does:

```
In [133]: np.array(list(h[:,0])).shape
Out[133]: (2, 5, 5, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of *objects*; You can use `np.stack` to convert it to the shape you need if you are sure all the sub elements have the same shape:

```
np.stack(a[:,0])
```

---

```
a = np.array([[np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2), 1.]]*5)

a.shape
# (5, 2)

a[:,0].shape
# (5,)

a[:,0][0].shape
# (4, 3, 2)

np.stack(a[:,0]).shape
# (5, 4, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to believe that Numpy can magically divine your intent. As @Barmar explains in the comments, when you slice a shape(5,2) array with `[:, 0]` you get all rows of the first column of that array. Each element of that slice is a shape(4,3,2) array. Numpy is giving you exactly what you asked for.

If you want to convert that into a shape(5,4,3,2) array you'll need to perform further processing to extract the elements from the shape(4,3,2) arrays.